# Just a pink screen after "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade". My laptop is new and it came with ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, updates, dell, screen, inspiron

Yesterday, I received my laptop Dell Inspiron and I did Ubuntu installing. It comes with Ubuntu. When I finished, in terminal, I did this commands: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade. A long time after, the upgrade finished. To test, I restarted my laptop and a purple screen appears. Just this. I couldn't login. I needed to go back to the factory installation. Can someone help me? I am new in Ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to return to factory mode?
Because the only method that can fix it is to download the ubuntu 18 or 19 .iso, which is free from this page:

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If you have other computers with windows system you have to do the following.
Then with the rufus program you throw an EMPTY USB with the ubuntu iso and when finished, you insert this USB to your device and if it starts by default, if not, you have to enter the bios to start from the USB. Link to download rufus:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/698ediiqe6n09tr/Rofus-TutosDaniHD.rar/file

Link to boot the iso with rufus:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5ZTGIrjBsU

Also if you have just bought it you should call the store or the supplier and explain that after an update the computer failed.

Comment: " if you have just bought it you should call the store or the supplier and explain that after an update the computer failed" Truer words were never said

Comment: Thank you! I returned to factory mode and the problem persisted when I did the sudo again. I contected Dell and they said that the problem is image, so I need to install Ubuntu again by the site that you told me. Now, I'm in trouble with this. I already downloaded and the bootable flash drive. I don't know what I do now.

Comment: As it shows you in the video I sent you for the boot with the rufus program. You have to insert the USB to your computer off. Then you start it, sometimes run the program alone. If it does not you have to enter the bios as follows.
You turn off the equipment and when you turn on quickly you have to try to type one of the following keys repeatedly: F10, F11, F12, F8 or F2.

Comment: This depends on the team, when you enter the bios you have to look for something like "Boot order" or the "boot" tab or in the advanced options tab.
When you find it you will have to put the USB devices up to the top with the ocpions indicated by your bios.
Then you simply save the changes and exit. The computer will restart and you just have to install ubuntu graphically so you will not get lost, just read well what it tells you.